# How to proof the Big-omega for general polynomial case?

Tags: algorithm, math

Big omega(Ω) definition is this.

The function f(n) = Ω(g(n)) , iff there exist positive constants c and n0 such that f(n) >= c*g(n) for all n, n>=n0.

Here a one theorem.

[image]

I want to prove this, **without using 'limit'**. I can find easy to use limit.

I thinking many hours and searching in internet, but i can't find it. Just limit...
Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

```
|Am.n^m + Am-1.n^m-1 + … A1.n + A0| <= n^m (|Am| + |Am-1|/n + … + |A1|/n^m-1 + |A0|/n^m)
```

Choose some `n0` and set

```
c = (|Am| + |Am-1|/n0 + … + |A1|/n0^m-1 + |A0|/n0^m).
```

This guarantees that

```
n >= n0 implies |f(n)| <= c.n^m
```

because `c(n) < c(n0)`.

Comment: um, it's big-o. my question is big-omega. f(n) >= c*g(n).

Comment: @lana756: oops, yes. But this method can easily be adapted.